# Show characters counter on frontpage in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, counter

I want to add textarea with function to count number of characters which user typed on frontext, for example counter under textarea in form.
Including special characters, space, tabulator etc.

Comment: Sounds like a nice plan - where's your approach?

Comment: sounds like a job for javascript.

Comment: Okay, I found code for JS. I will try. I want to build some page for testing.